# Swiper.js will not work on top of css animation

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations, carousel, swiper.js

I am trying to make a slider using Swiper.js.

Ive managed to get the slider to work but i would like to use CSS @keyframes animation in order to make the slider automatically slide in one direction infinitely.

The problem is that when i apply the CSS the slider breaks and no longer has any of the functionality provided by swiper.js

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Swiper demo</title>
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"
    />
    <!-- Link Swiper's CSS -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css"
    > 

    <!-- Demo styles -->
    <style>
      body {
        min-height: 100vh;
        display: grid;
        place-items: center;
      }

      .swiper {
        height: 250px;
        margin: auto;
        position: relative;
        width: 90%;
        display: grid;
        place-items: center;
        overflow: hidden;
      }

    
      .slide-track {
        display: flex;
        width: calc(250px * 9);
        animation: scroll 40s linear infinite; 
      }

    
      @keyframes scroll {
        0% {
          transform: translateX(0);
        }
        100% {
          transform: translateX(calc(-250px * 4.5));
        }
      }


      .swiper-slide {
        height: 200px;
        width: 250px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 15px;
        perspective: 100px;
      }

      .swiper-slide img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
      }

     
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Swiper -->
    <div class="swiper">
      <div class="slide-track">
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src ="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/03/20/16/21/iguana-7081261_960_720.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src ="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/03/20/16/21/iguana-7081261_960_720.jpg"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src ="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/03/20/16/21/iguana-7081261_960_720.jpg"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src ="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/03/20/16/21/iguana-7081261_960_720.jpg"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src ="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/03/20/16/21/iguana-7081261_960_720.jpg"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src ="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/03/20/16/21/iguana-7081261_960_720.jpg"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src ="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/03/20/16/21/iguana-7081261_960_720.jpg"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src ="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/03/20/16/21/iguana-7081261_960_720.jpg"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src ="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/03/20/16/21/iguana-7081261_960_720.jpg"></div>
        
    <!-- Swiper JS -->
     <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script> 

    <!-- Initialize Swiper -->
    <script>
        var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
        slidesPerView: 4,
        spaceBetween: 30,
        loop: true,
        freeMode: true
      }); 
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You might be able to do that using the swiper.js builtin functions instead.

```
loop: true,
autoplay: {
  delay: 1,
  disableOnInteraction: false
},
speed: 4000,
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Swiper demo</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
  <!-- Link Swiper's CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" />

  <!-- Demo styles -->
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    body {
      background: #eee;
      font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #000;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    .swiper {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    .swiper-slide {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 18px;
      background: #fff;
      /* Center slide text vertically */
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
      -webkit-justify-content: center;
      justify-content: center;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
      -webkit-align-items: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    .swiper-slide img {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
    }
    
    .swiper-wrapper {
      transition-timing-function: linear;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Swiper -->
  <div class="swiper mySwiper">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  </div>

  <!-- Swiper JS -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>


  <!-- Initialize Swiper -->
  <script>
    var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
      slidesPerView: 3,
      spaceBetween: 30,
      loop: true,
      autoplay: {
        delay: 1,
        disableOnInteraction: false
      },
      slidesPerView: "auto",
      speed: 4000,
      pagination: {
        el: ".swiper-pagination",
        clickable: true
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes this does help a tremendous amount but i would also like to use the 'freeMode' property. It just seems to help everything move a little smoother when dragging it however when i do so it doesnt seem to slide the same without it. Slides will have the same pace until they reach the end of the slide where it slows down until the next one is reached. Do you know how i may fix that?